# Why is Magento 2 local developer mode site with nginx and xdebug enabled is super slow?

Tags: magento-2.1

I am getting a 50 second server response time for a category page.

When processing, the following is shown in `top`:

`4312 www-data  20   0  488280 146704  41816 R  99.7  1.8   1:11.54 php-fpm7.0`

I have `x-debug` enabled with `php7.0-fpm` and `nginx`.
Developer mode is on and I am developing so I am not looking for a `turn on production mode` answer.
I am using magento `2.1.2`.
I am also using a `redis-server` cache backend.
I am also on `php 7.0.14` on `ubuntu 16.04`.

After enabling `xdebug remote debugging` and adding a breakpoint the average time to get a server response is a whopping 3 minutes. That is messed up.
I am using atom with the `php-debug` package for `atom` to debug.

I am also on an SSD, so read and writes should be fast right?

After running `dstat -D hda` these are the results:

[image: disk usage read and writes]

**Update: After disabling js merging and minification**

After disabling js merging and minification as well as css merging server response improved to about 7 to 8 seconds. Thanks @Konstantin, it is now bearable.

Comment: disable css/js merging  (stores > configuration > advanced > developer) and report back

Comment: It worked, gone from 30sec/1min down to about 7 - 8 seconds. Much better. Are there any other tips you can give?

Comment: There is another problem...when atom hits the breakpoint it keeps processing for about 20 seconds.

Comment: what happens if you set xdebug.remote_autostart = 0. then use debug cookie/param to enable disable xdebug. at the moment it is probably connecting on every request. taken from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736304/enabling-xdebug-remote-debug-makes-apache-server-very-slow

Comment: With each step over atom burns CPU at 100% for about 20 seconds,

Comment: What happens when you disable xdebug? Does it bring down server response time to around 15 seconds? What do you see when you do cache: status  ? Is your phone memory limit around. 700mb?

Comment: Disabling `xdebug` works quite well takes it down to 15 seconds, but then you can't debug

Comment: Did you find any proper configuration for xdebug ? I was getting mad with my local environment, i did not thought of xdebug doing that !

Comment: Nope unfortunately not. I've said goodbye to magento. Don't need it in my life.

Answer (score 0):

you should check your cache configuration. Some of them should be enabled. E.g configuration.