# Why is default Luma theme so slow (Time to interactive) on PageSpeed insight?

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, pagespeed

I had a bad result on Google Pagespeed Insight on small Magento Websites, using the default theme and modifying only a little stuff, plus adding static content to homepages.

And Pagespeed Insight ratings are bad, more on mobile.

So I installed an empty 2.2.8 shop (no categories, no product) to try to find out what I was doing wrong.

I tested with GTMetrix and get an A (99%) on PageSpeed (so I guess it's not a configuration problem)

JS and CSS are minified, even HTML. I even installed a Varnish to be sure!

But PageSpeed Insight ratings are as bad as with modified Luma. (around 38-40)

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftestmg2.g-softs.net%2F (the link might not be valid in time, it's just a test website)

So does anyone knows why the default template got so bad ratings?

Is there a way to improve it easily (I'm more of a backend than a frontend dev)?

Do you know ultra basic templates with good PageSpeed ratings?

Thanks in advance!

JM

Edit: I just tried with a Magento 2.3.1. Same results.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single answer to this question. Take a look at this git issue. Makes for an interesting read. I'm sure there are other git issues. But I found this one.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/20974

Other than that how to improve scores there are suggestions on here

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273133/70343

More for improving general speed. But will improve the score.

But some of it cant be fixed even with an extension and a better theme.  In summary, it's how Magento works in terms of loading assets.

I think that's part of the reason they are focusing on a PWA theme. Which is something different entirely.

Comment: Hi Dominic, thanks for your answer. I think I've checked all the points on the list from the stackexchange link you give (or at least all I can do in setting a temporary Magento). But again this is the default store without any categories, products or 3rd party stuff. There is obviously a problem with the CSS part, but what I notice is the around 20s off Time to interactive I have, and I think it have a lot to do with it.

Comment: Found this too. More of the same really https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Hosting-Performance/magento-2-amp-pagespeed/m-p/50619 bottom line you can only get so far with this framework

Comment: Thanks again Dominic. But this links is from before July 2018 when Google changed their PageSpeed Insights methods, resulting of the fall of the mobile results. Before that, all tests were green !

Comment: Yikes you're not kidding. From that community post https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.igorschimberg.de%2F&tab=mobile dropped to [M] 32/100  [D] 59/100.  Originally was [M] 72/100 [D] 83/100.  There is this https://amasty.com/google-page-speed-optimizer-for-magento-2.html extension but really can't see how you can overcome some of these highlighted issues.  Especially `Eliminate render-blocking resources`.  That is basically how requirejs works.  Wait here whilst I fetch what you need.

Answer (score 0):

ignore these, google pagespeed tester shows some crap for long time.

we usually run tester either:

1 - looking at netowrk panel in Chrome browser.

you can trust only yourself.

2 - from our own servers.

simulating user request with some high load.

3 - https://www.webpagetest.org/

run some basic test, just to see those fancy metrics from specific region :)